# can't write unknown attribute `example` typed_store - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I have this models where I wanna update my typestored columns using update_columns active record

I have searched numerous answers in stack, doesn't seems to have lot of resources regarding typestored.

show.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag print_booking_path(@booking), method: 'post' do %>
 <%= label_tag :name %>
 <%= text_field_tag :name, '', class: 'form-control' %>
 <%= label_tag :age %>
 <%= text_field_tag :age, '', class: 'form-control' %>
 <%= submit_tag "Print", class: "btn btn-default" %>
 <%= link_to 'Cancel', '#', class: 'btn btn-default', data: { dismiss: 'modal' } %>
<% end %>
```

bookings_controller

```
def print
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
    if @booking.print_model(current_user, params[:name], params[:age])
      render :print
    else
      render :print
    end
  end
```

booking model

```
def print_model(user, name_test, age_test)
 self.update_columns(name: name_test, age: age_test)
end
```

typestore under booking model

```
typed_store :profile, coder: PostgresCoder do |i|
 i.string :name, default: ""
 i.integer :age, default: 0
end
```

the error appeared to be like this
can't write unknown attribute `name`

it's same like if I wanna to update like this self.increment!(:age)

Comment: Hi, can you show your model as a whole?

Comment: what kind of information that i need to provide? @GuilhermeNunes

Comment: Please show the model, the migration and the code you execute along with the error it produces.

Comment: It would be interesting also to know how did you configure the store, because there are some different ways to make it. :)

Comment: Awesome, I have updated my answer down below, I hope it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few tests here, and I don't know if it makes sense, but in case of updating stores, all the typestored columns are inside just one real column in the database (that are a normally in hash or Json).

So the straight foward way to do it is to wrap in brackets.

Try changing:

```
self.update_columns( name: name_test, age: age_test )
```

To:

```
self.update_columns( profile: { name: name_test, age: age_test} )
```

Comment: Ive solve the problem actually, but this is still one of the great answer cause we do in one line only, thanks